# Metodo do mongoose depreciado

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão com mblab mas o método de conexão está depreciado.
Versão do metodo é 4.9.7.
O que eu preciso é 4.13.7.

Estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
const config = require('./config/secret');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect(config.database, function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("connected to the database");
});

app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const mainRoutes = require('./routes/main');

app.use(mainRoutes);


app.listen(3030, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log(`Running on port ${3030}`);
});
```

secret.js

```js
module.exports = {
  database: ''

}
```

main.js

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('main/landing');

});

router.get('/create-new-user', (req, res, next) => {
  var user = new User();
  user.email = "gtav@gmail.com"
  user.name = "Jack";
  user.password = "123456";
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json("Successfully created");
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

user.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  name: String,
  password: String,
  photo: String,
  tweets: [{
    tweet: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tweet' }
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

```
dependencias": {
    “body-parser”: “^1.18.2”,
    “express”: “^4.16.2”,
    “express-handlebars”: “^3.0.0”,
    “hbs”: “^4.0.1”,
    “mongoose”: “^4.13.7”,
    “morgan”: “^1.9.0”
}
```

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/265181/edit) pergunta e coloque o código ao invés de imagens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme citado pelo autor por comentário, o mesmo estava obtendo o seguinte erro:

> DeprecationWarning: open() is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use openUri() instead, or set the useMongoClient option if using connect() or createConnection(). Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple crede ntials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.

A mensagem de erro informa que, para corrigir o problema, você deve utilizar o método `openUri()` ou se estiver utilizando o método `connect()` ou `createConnection()` configurar a opção `useMongoClient` como `true`.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bd', { useMongoClient: true })
```

Comment: Eu acho que você não entedeu. Minhas depedencias estão atualizadas mas aprendi a fazer o metodo de conexão em uma versão desatualizada.

Comment: Esse aqui:

mongoose.connect(config.database, function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("connected to the database");
});

Comment: (node:7844) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple crede
ntials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.

Comment: Então passe o parâmetro `useMongoClient: true`, veja: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp', { useMongoClient: true })`

Comment: Deu certo. Refaço a pergunta ou voce refaz a resposta?

Comment: Windows 7 .....

Comment: Pronto. Ajeitei a resposta.